# Changing simulator changes mysterious behavior of launching safari after tap gesture

Tags: swiftui

When I tap in the iPad simulator while my app is running in the foreground, the app mysteriously goes to home screen and then Safari is launched (but simulator does not switch to Safari, it remains on the home screen).  I commented out all of my code and replaced it with the code below, and still the behavior persists.  But if I switch to a different simulator, iPhone for example, I don't get this behavior.  What's going on?  The behavior appears to be as if tapping on a url link and then a web browser would be launched - but I have no such code, and when I open the safari browser it doesn't display any meaningful address.  It doesn't matter where I tap on the screen btw.

```
            return VStack {
                Text("TEST TEST TEST")
            }
```

EDIT: This mysterious behavior went away "mysteriously" after I quit the simulator and restarted.  I also had mysterious build linking issues in Xcode, and after quitting the simulator they also vanished.  Xcode Version 11.3.1 (11C504)

Answer (score 0):

By restarting the Simulator all mysterious and unwarranted issues with interaction appear to be reset.  No clue why the issues arise in the first place.